# laravel 5.7 multi auth email verification

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to set up an email verification for `job_seeker` but after I register a new `job_seeker` I redirect to profile page which must be protected with `job_seeker_verified` middleware 
in normal case I must be redirecting to `job_seeker/verify` which uses the route named `job_seeker_verification.notice` with the controller `verification_controller` and the function that shows the view with verify message but instead I get

> forbidden page 403

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\job_seeker;

use App\Job_seeker;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class job_seeker_profile_controller extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['job_seeker_auth', 'job_seeker_verified']);
    }

    public function show_profile(Job_seeker $job_seeker)
    {
        return view('profile.job_seeker_profile');
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Closure;

class Ensure_Job_Seeker_Is_Verified
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $guard == 'job_seeker';
        if (
            !Auth::guard($guard)->user() || (Auth::guard($guard)->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
                !Auth::guard($guard)->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())
        ) {
            return $request->expectsJson()
                ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                : Redirect::route('job_seeker_verification.notice');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\job_seeker;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Job_seeker;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;

class Verification_Controller extends Controller
{
    use VerifiesEmails;
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected $redirectTo = 'job_seeker.profile';
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('job_seeker_auth');
        $this->middleware('signed');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('resend');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()
            ? redirect($this->redirectPath())
            : view('profile.job_seeker_verify');
    }
    public function verify(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->route('id') != $request->user()->getKey()) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
        }

        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        }

        if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($request->user()));
        }

        return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('job_seeker_verified', true);
    }
}
```

```php
Route::get('job_seeker_email.resend', [
    'as'=>'job_seeker_email.verification.resend', 'uses'=>'job_seeker\Job_Seeker_Verication_email@resend'
    ]);
Route::get('job_seeker/verify', [
    'as'=>'job_seeker_verification.notice', 'uses'=>'job_seeker\Verification_Controller@show'
    ]);
Route::get('job_seeker/verify/{id}', [
    'as'=>'job_seeker_verification.verify','uses'=>'job_seeker\Verification_Controller@verify'
    ]);
```

Comment: Post your `verification_controller` code, am assuming you're passing the same middleware in the controller's constructor

Comment: And don't post code as images, use the Stack Overflow text area to paste and format the code properly

Comment: CaddyDZ can you see now

Comment: Yes and answered